# How can my DIR path be narrowed down better with unknown folder name in the path?

Tags: vba, cmd, directory

I have a vba script that will loop through all xml files in a folder using CMD as follows

`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR ""D:\data\*.xml*"" /S /B /A:-D")`

How can I change the path so it only looks inside folders named "1" and ignore folders named "2", "3", etc where there is a unknown folder name in the path before as shown below?

`CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR ""D:\data\UNKNOWN\1\*.xml*"" /S /B /A:-D")`

This will narrow down the returned number of paths from 34,000 to 1500

Comment: [Search for a file with wildcards in the path using Windows command line](https://superuser.com/q/524441)

Comment: ^^ I was just gonna suggest adding an earlier wildcard in for UNKNOWN

Comment: Literally just found this myself, damn, am I able to use powershell instread of cmd in vba?

Comment: You can use CMD too, see my answer.

Comment: I am getting an access denied error when trying with powershell unfortunately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
Sub test()

Dim list As Variant

list = Split(CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR /S /B  D:\data\* | findstr 1 | findstr xml").StdOut.ReadAll, vbNewLine)

End Sub
```

Comment: hmmm I'm getting 0 files returned wit this, is that the correct syntax of quotations for the 1 and the xml?

Comment: Managed to get it working with ```CreateObject("WScript.Shell").Exec("CMD /C DIR /S /B  D:\data\*.xml | findstr 1")``` Thank you for the help